# How can I get the list of all columns in a BigQuery table and dataset

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I would like to query all columns and their description in a table/dataset. I'm looking similar metadata tables like `__TABLES_SUMMARY__` and `__TABLES__`.

The goal is to build a data dictionary report in Data Studio for the BigQuery tables.

Answer (score 12):

You can now query the list of columns that way:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type
FROM `myproject`.mydataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'mytable'
```

You need to replace  myproject, mydataset, mytable by your values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`bq show`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_show) in CLI

[`For example`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#getting_information_about_tables),

> Issue the bq show command to display all table information. Use the --schema flag to display only table schema information. The --format flag can be used to control the output.
>
> If you are getting information about a table in a project other than your default project, add the project ID to the dataset in the following format: [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].

```
bq show --schema --format=prettyjson [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[TABLE]
```

> Where:
>
> [PROJECT_ID] is your project ID.
>   [DATASET] is the name of the dataset.
>   [TABLE] is the name of the table.

Similarly for [`dataset`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#getting_information_about_datasets) :

```
bq show --format=prettyjson [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET]
```

Comment: Thank you Mikhail! Can we get similar results from WebUI query?

Comment: querying such info is not supported unfortunately. but there is always work around - search here in SO - I answered few similar questions already

Comment: Appreciate your help! My goal is to build a data dictionary report in Data Studio for the BigQuery tables. Looks like an improvement required on BigQuery.

Comment: you can have daily process that produces all the tables, datasets metadata you need using CLI or API and loading those into some table which then can be used for Data Studio report(s)

Comment: Agreed! That's the last option I have :)